# Storing Array vs. Single Value Comparison

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, multidimensional-array, variant

Original code stores `A6:A50` of dynamic values into an array and when they change compares their differences and prints their differences `diff` to `Sheet2` along with some other values pulled from the `Sheet1 (Dashboard)`. It works great when monitoring the recalculation of `A6:A50` and storing that column as a 2D variant array.

Goal is to monitor a single cell `F3` on `Sheet 1 (Dashboard)` instead of `A6:A50`. Excel crashes now with my edited code.

Code in `Sheet1 (Dashboard)`

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()

End Sub

    Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    
        Dim keyCells As Range
        Dim i As Long
        Dim diff As Range
        Dim cKey As Range 
        Dim ValueArray As Variant
    
        If Worksheets("Dashboard").ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
            On Error GoTo SafeExit
                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual: Application.EnableEvents = False: Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
            Set keyCells = Me.Range("F3").Value
                For i = 1 To UBound(myArr)
                    Set cKey = keyCells(i, 1)
    
                    If cKey.Value <> myArr(i, 1) Then
                        diff = (cKey.Value - myArr(i, 1))
                        NextRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
                        ValueArray = Array(Me.Cells(i + 2, "A").Value, Me.Cells(i + 2, "B").Value, diff, Me.Cells(i + 2, "C").Value, _
                                Me.Cells(i + 2, "D").Value, Me.Cells(i + 2, "E").Value, Me.Cells(i + 5, "F").Value, _
                                Me.Cells(i + 2, "G").Value)
    
                        With Sheet2.Cells(NextRow, "A").Resize(, UBound(ValueArray) + 1)
                            .Value = ValueArray
                        End With
                        NextRow = NextRow + 1
                    End If
                Next i
    End If
    SafeExit:
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic: Application.EnableEvents = True: Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
        Call PopulateBA: 
    End Sub
```

Code in `ThisWorkbook`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
PopulateBA
End Sub
```

Code in `Module1`

```
Public myArr()
Public Sub PopulateBA()
    Dim myArr As Variant
    myArr = Sheet1.Range("F3").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set cKey = keyCells(i, 1)` is wrong. `keyCells` contains a single cell's value (whatever is in F3). It's not a Range, and it makes no sense for you to try to use it as one. It's a single cell.

Comment: `myArr = Sheet1.Range("F3").Value` Then `myArr` is NOT an array anymore.  `Set keyCells = Me.Range("F3").Value` is wrong. You can't set a value to an object.  Which cell is supposed to compare with F3?

Comment: `F3` is constantly changing. Goal is to monitor `F3` when it changes from 10 to 45 as an example it will print `diff` 35. Then it changes from 45 to 65 and the next print `diff` is 20 and so on.

Comment: If you goal is to monitor a cell, `Worksheet_Change` event is a better option.

Comment: The `Change` event only fires when a cell is changed by the user or by an external link. In my case a formula is in the cell and I monitor the change from the worksheet recalculation. A `Calculate` event will respond to a formula recalculation but a `Change` event will not - unless you monitor the input cells for the formula instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign single value to a Variant array you should `ReDim` it first.

```
Public myArr() 
Public Sub PopulateBA()
    ReDim myArr(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
    myArr(1, 1) = Sheet1.Range("F3").Value 
End Sub
```

And you shouldn't use `Value` when you assign to object variable:

```
Set keyCells = Me.Range("F3")
```